# How can I access Tag property of TreeViewItem in a background thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, treeview, treeviewitem

I have a tree view in a wpf window. And for each tree view item in the tree view I store the related object in its Tag property.I am implementing search functionality on the tree view. And I run the search in a different thread so as to not block the UI. And during search operation I search the information in object stored in the tag property of tree view item. But the problem is that tag property is not accessible in a different thread. I do not want to use the tree view's dispatcher for accessing the tag property as then the program will switch between UI thread and background thread for every tag access. Then there will be no point in running the search in background. What can I do?

Comment: You're using the treeview the wrong way, I suppose. The wpf treeview (as opposed to the winforms one) is to be used with view models in the datacontext of each item. You are expected to maintain the hierarchy of view models yourself, and then you can access and search them as you like. A good, though antique, read is this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

Comment: Best way is just not use `Tag` property to store this information. WPF is build with Model-View concept in mind, and it's better to not play against this concept by storing model data in view (`Tag`) elements.

Comment: There is just no conceivable reason that you need to do this at all.  Simply pass the text to search for when you start the task.  When the selection changes before the task is done then cancel it and create another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I do?

You *cannot* access the `Tag` property of the `TreeViewItem` from any other thread than the one which it was originally created on, that is the UI/dispatcher thread.

So you will have to either use the dispatcher to marshall the code that access the property back to the UI thread, run all code on the UI thread, or use a different approach that doesn't make use of the `Tag` property to store the information about the related object.

These are your only options I am afraid.